# How can I compare field from JSONB column in Laravel?

Tags: json, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I have a column with type JSONB(postgresql), and I need in checking of one field of this JSON structure. For example `data->vegetables->tomato->weight->value  >= "12"`. I used `whereJsonContains` but it only supports `= or include`, also I used `where('data->vegetable->tomato->weight->value','>=',12)` and result is wrong I read that it might be because of types. It is string in Json structure and 12 is string too. But I know that I can do like this (int)12 and it will be solved. But can not understand how to do that in Eloquent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like that `query->whereRaw('(data -> \'vegetables\' -> \'tomato\' -> \'weight\' ->> \'value\')::int >= '. (int)12)`  Here `data` is a column of table, `->` shows column of JSON structure, `->>` shows value of column, `::int` - it is like CAST.